# scrollable display:table-cell - not able to have fixed dimensions

Tags: html, css, image, css-position, css-tables

I am using `display:table`,`table-row`,`table-cell` styles applied to some divs. One of the table-cell ones has a huge image in it. I want to set a fixed width and height for the cell, and make it scrollable so you can move around the image.

The trouble is using `overflow:scroll`, or even `overflow:hidden`, with a fixed width and height doesn't seem to force the size of the table-cell.

How can I force the div containing the image to be a fixed height/width?

```css
    .table-wrap{
      display:table;
    }
    .table-wrap > div{
      display:table-row;
    }
    .table-wrap > div > div{
      display:table-cell;
    }
    #map{
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      overflow:scroll;
    }
```

```html
<div id="interface">
  <div class="table-wrap">
    <div id="top">
      <div id="map">
        <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/ZhGEqAP.jpg">
      </div>
      <div id="sidebar">
        sidebar
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-wrap">
    <div id="bottom">
      <div class="bla">
        bla
      </div>
      <div class="bla">
        bla
      </div>
      <div class="bla">
        bla
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can only fix one dimension for images- otherwise the image will 'stretch out` and that does not preserve aspect ratio...

Comment: I am not adjusting the image size. I am adjusting the size of the container. I want most of the image to be hidden by the containing div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the `table algorithm` that is used by CSS, you won't be able to restrict the image inside a `table-cell` unless you give it directly on the `img` element.

I think your best bet here is to use `position` the `img` as `absolute` and get it to look the way you want.

Snippet below:

```css
.table-wrap {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-wrap > div {
  display: table-row;
}
.table-wrap > div > div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#map {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}
#map img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="interface">
  <div class="table-wrap">
    <div id="top">
      <div id="map">
        <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/ZhGEqAP.jpg">
      </div>
      <div id="sidebar">
        sidebar
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-wrap">
    <div id="bottom">
      <div class="bla">
        bla
      </div>
      <div class="bla">
        bla
      </div>
      <div class="bla">
        bla
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```